# Jenkins declarative pipeline not reading stages or steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I am new to the jenkins world and not sure why it's not reading the steps in my declarative pipeline.

I am sure that it's something simple but I can't seem to see where the error is.

```
import cloud.GitClient
import cloud.SlackClient

def call(body) {
    def parameters = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = parameters
    body()

    pipeline {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          cloud parameters['buildCloudId']
        }
      }
      stages {
        stage('Inform Build Start') {
          steps {
            script{
              slackClient.warn('Starting build!')
            }
          }
        }
        stage('Build Docker Images') {
          steps {
            checkout scm
            container('docker') {
              withCredentialsee(usernamePassword(credentialsId: parameters.docker.credentialsId, usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')) {
                sh """
                echo "\$PASSWORD" | docker login -u \$USERNAME --password-stdin hub.containers
                ./build.sh
                """
              }
            }
          }
          post {
            failure {
              script {
                slackClient.failed("Docker backend build *FAILED*! <${env.BUILD_URL}console|See log> for details.")
              }
            }
            success {
              script {
                slackClient.success("Docker backend build *COMPLETED*! <${env.BUILD_URL}console|See log> for details.")
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In jenkins, everything shows green, but logs shows that nothing was ran at all.

Comment: Not sure if Jenkins can parse the Jenkinsfile correctly if you use it in a function. Nothing can fail if nothing is executed, doesnt it?

Comment: I've seen other declarative pipelines formatted similarly and they are working just fine. Which is why it's confusing to me as to why it's not working.